# `emacs24` package not available on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, emacs

I use Emacs24 for testing Emacs modes. `emacs24` package is not available on Ubuntu 17.10. Any external ppa or help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/emacs24

Or

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cassou/emacs    
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install emacs24 emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg
```

Comment: `ppa:cassou/emacs` is deprecated. It is not zesty, it is artful thus the link you might have wanted to give might be [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/emacs24) (In that link `emacs24` and `emacs24-nox` have no description). Still no luck with Emacs24 installation.